# How can I redirect users from one dir to another in Nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, unix, redirect, webserver

I've added the following redirection rule, but it doesn't work. It should redirect any requests from one folder to another, e.g. `/en/content/images/image.jpg` to `/content/images/image.jpg`

```
location  ~ ^/en/content/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass   $scheme://mydomain/content/$1;
}
```

Is there any errors in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/en/content/(.*\.jpg)$ {
  return 301 /content/$1;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, that's why I tried proxy. But I found that 301 didn't work because of other rule above in my config. I just moved my 301 redirect upper and it worked.